# SQL Server OPENQUERY error

Tags: sql-server, casting, sum, openquery

I'm using OPENQUERY on SQL Server 2008, I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT familyCode, sum(member) FROM customers')
```

I get this error:

> Column familyCode or expression in SELECT list not valid

When I run the code without `SUM`, it works perfectly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT familyCode, member FROM customers')
```

What's the correct syntax for including the `SUM` function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `group by` clause when using an aggregation function like `SUM`

```
SELECT familyCode, sum(member) FROM customers group by familyCode
```